# Get the data from the pojo classes of the JSON file

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following JSON array as file in my Jersey project in `src/main/resources/routes.txt`. I want to convert it to Java object to get the time in the case of `mon-fri or sat or sun`. I have generated the classes below with the help of [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) link. How can I get the time from the ArrivalTime class with this generated structure? Should I put all these generated classes as inner classes of the root class or separately?

I appreciate any help.

**JSON simple:**

```
[{
   "route": 1,
   "info": {
              "stops": {
                          "arrival_time": {"mon-fri": ["04:24","05:10","05:40"],
                                       "sat": ["05:34","05:55","06:15"],
                                       "sun": ["07:00","08:00","05:40"]

                                       },
                          "stops_name": "Tension Way"
                        },
              "direction": "Surrey Quays"
           }
}]
```

**Generated classes:**

```
 public class Root {

    private Integer route;
    private Info info;

    }

    public class Info {

    private Stops stops;
    private String direction;   
    }

    public class Stops {

    private ArrivalTime arrivalTime;
    private String stopsName;  
    }

    public class ArrivalTime {

    private List<String> monFri = new ArrayList<String>();

    private List<String> sat = new ArrayList<String>();

    private List<String> sun = new ArrayList<String>();

    }
```

**Code:**

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FileReader fileReader;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader("src/main/resources");
        try {
            Root readValue = mapper.readValue(fileReader, Root.class);
            readValue.getInfo();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> monFri = readValue().getInfo().getStops().getArrivalTime().getMonFri();
```

That's the structure of the JSON object, and is also the structure of the Java object mapped to the JSON.

The classes should be top-level classes, or static nested classes, but not inner classes.